# CodeFirst using EntityFramework not creating database in sql server Management

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entityframework.I am trying to create database using Codefirst approach of entityFramework. I have my Code here :

```
public class AppointmentInfo
{
   public AppointmentInfo()
   { }
   public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
   public string Subject { get; set; }
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey="UniqueId "]
   public Client client { get; set; }

   public string Chargeable { get; set; }
   public string Activity { get; set; }
   public string DetailText { get; set; }
   public string Employee { get; set; }
}


public class Client
{
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get;set;}
}

public class AppointmentsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppointmentsDbContext()
        : base("AppointmentConnectionString")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<AppointmentInfo> AppointmentInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> clients { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I defined my connectionstring in app.config :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AppointmentConnectionString" 
connectionString="Server=DHRUV;Database=Client_Appointments;Integrated Security=true" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

This does not create database in Sql server management.What I forgot to implement ? How to create Database ?
Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although EF code first should create the database on first run of the application. Try setting this in your DbContext:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());
```

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework will not create the datatabase 'DHRUV' for you, you have to create it and add your account to it's security table. EF will then the current state of the database and excecute pending migrations.